# ASP.NET MVC5 - Doing Create and Edit in the same ActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC and I am trying to do something that should be simple but I can't quite seem to get it.

The default MVC templates set you up with Details, Edit, Create action results. I am trying to combine these steps all into one. Details we can do away with because Edit is basically details. In the Edit ActionResult I would like to do something like this:

If there is no id or id is 0 then the fields should be empty so a new one can be created. Otherwise, if there is an id and record exists populate the fields and do an update if info is changed. I have repository functions that handle create/update.

Comment: Ok, and?  What is your question exactly?  Are you asking if you can do it?  Are you asking HOW to do it?  Are you asking IF you should do it?  Are you asking us to do it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'd go a RedirectToAction("Edit") for example, depending on if the id has a value or not. This keeps the views separate and easier to mantain.

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Edit");
            }
            // else....
        }
```

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToAction%28%29-vs-return-Redirect%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToRoute%28%29.html

Comment: Does this mean you still have 2 separate but similar views? Edit and Create?

Comment: Yeah as with MVC its better to keep these separate, so in future if you wanted to change how the edit was handled for example then you would just change that particular view.  The way you describe almost makes it like an ASP.net application and you aren't taking advantage of MVC having all the switch logic on page load, although this up to debate.

Comment: My background is in webforms and I am used to using the same page for everything. If ID=0 then nothing populates and on save it adds new record, if ID > 0 then fields populate and on save it updates. Thank you for translating this. I still want the workflow to be easy for the user. But you are saying the MVC way is so that when they click Add New it will go to Create and when they click something like View Details it will go to Edit. If they go to Edit and it can't find then redirect to Create.

Comment: The user wouldn't tell any different, all you are doing is creating individual views, so within the edit one you would create a form, with fields and text boxes etc in there, then on the form action you'd save this.  You would have another view called "View" for example that is just a list of labels and doesnt need to have any forms in theory.

Comment: Ohhh ok see that is where my inexperience with MVC comes into play. You are saying I can use the same view but call 2 different action results within it? So then the user won't be going to either /Create/ and /Edit/ but just /Edit/ for everything?

Comment: Quite the opposite, for every action you should have a view and then in the Index action like I have shown an example for above you would redirect this to whichever you need to. I recommend you give MVC a proper research here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: It is possible to use one action but as nik0lias stated, for maintainability it's better to employ three"RedirecttoAction" as exampled.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your approach and saw a couple of projects going the same path. Except making sure `Id`'s seed cannot be 0 for an existing entity (Which is default behavior in EF).

However I'd make sure I'm not going to end up with a view/action with many switch-cases/conditions. If so, it's kind of saying edit/create are better off being separate.